# Textcontent without Ajax loading?

Tags: html, ajax

Is it possible to place text content on a Shopware homepage directly in the HTML code and thus not have it reloaded via AJAX? If yes: how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

**How it works?**
Place a default/fallback text in the HTML. Make sure you set an ID to the div container around.
e.g.:

```
<div id="containerid">This is my default text</div>
```

Then replace the content with the text you just loaded successfully from another resource (your backend for example)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/text/resource/path",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (receivedText) { // ...is triggered after you received a response
        $('#containerid').text(receivedText);
    }
});
```